# How do I find nodes with whitespace at the end and get line position?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

How can I search a xml file for whitespace just before the close tag of any tag and get its actual position using `(IXmlLineInfo)`'s `LinePosition` property
For example in case of the below xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<main>
    <child1>anything</child1>
    <child2>whatever </child1>
    <pp>
        <ccl>i dont know</ccl>
        <ccp>1253 </ccp>
    </pp>
</main>
```

The output should be like

```
Whitespace found at position 4,19
Whitespace found at position 7,14
```

What is the easiest way of doing this using `XDocument`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First task is to find all nodes that ends with a space, then get the line info by casting them to `IXmlLineInfo`, assuming document is the `XDocument`:

```
document.Descendants()
        .Where(node => ((string)node).EndsWith(" "))
        .Select(node => node as IXmlLineInfo);
```

This will give you the line infos that contain line number and position of the node. If you want the find line position of the space, you will need to do some calculation on this value, i.e. add the length of the node's value to line position, you will get the position of the whitespace. Also you might need to add the lenght of node's name including opening and closing tags to find exact position.

Comment: in case of something like `<profile>abc<age>30 </age></profile>` your code shows both `age` and `profile` nodes but I only want `age` in this case..how can I do that...also I'm struggling to get the exact line position is well,,,can you help??